# Sequelize - Nested include with N:M relationships

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I've been struggling with an issue lately I can't seem to figure out. We basically have 3 models.
`User`, `Role`, `Organization`. A user is assigned to an organization with a Role. He can have multiple roles for an organization. For example

[image]

They are connected through another model `UserOrganization`
When I'm trying to fetch them all with includes with the below

```
{
    model: Organization,
    required : true,
    include: [
        {
            model: Role,
            required : true
        },
    ],
}
```

I'm getting back some strange results. The User is fine, the organizations of the user is fine BUT within that organization the Roles that are fetched are not from that specific user. Are the Roles assigned to that organization to whatever user.
[image]

userOrganization.js

```
    UserOrganization.belongsTo(models.Organization, {
        foreignKey: 'organization_id',
    });
    UserOrganization.belongsTo(models.User, {
        foreignKey: 'user_id',
    });
    UserOrganization.belongsTo(models.Role, {
        foreignKey: 'role_id',
    });
```

user.js

```
    User.belongsToMany(models.Organization, {
        through: {
            model: models.UserOrganization,
            unique: false,
        },
        foreignKey: 'user_id',
        otherKey: 'organization_id',
    });
    User.belongsToMany(models.Role, {
        through: {
            model: models.UserOrganization,
            unique: false,
        },
        foreignKey: 'user_id',
        otherKey: 'role_id',
    });
```

organization.js

```
     Organization.belongsToMany(models.F5Connection, {
        through: {
            model: models.OrganizationF5Connection,
            unique: false,
        },
        foreignKey: 'organization_id',
        otherKey: 'f5_connection_id',
    });
    Organization.belongsToMany(models.Role, {
        through: {
            model: models.UserOrganization,
            unique: false,
        },
        foreignKey: 'organization_id',
        otherKey: 'role_id',
    });
```

role.js

```
     Role.belongsToMany(models.User, {
        through: {
            model: models.UserOrganization,
            unique: false,
        },
        foreignKey: 'role_id',
        otherKey: 'user_id',
    });
    Role.belongsToMany(models.Organization, {
        through: {
            model: models.UserOrganization,
            unique: false,
        },
        foreignKey: 'role_id',
        otherKey: 'organization_id',
    });
```

Where have I gone wrong here ? Is there a way to fetch the Users organizations with the Roles assigned only to him ? The other solution would be to fetch the User Roles and then match them against the Organizations after the results.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're storing user's role and organization on the same level in one record in `UserOrganization`.
Keeping it in mind you need to define the following associations:

user.js

```js
User.hasMany(models.UserOrganization, {
        foreignKey: 'user_id'
    });
```

organization.js

```js
Organization.hasMany(models.UserOrganization, {
        foreignKey: 'organization_id'
    });
```

role.js

```js
Role.hasMany(models.UserOrganization, {
        foreignKey: 'role_id'
    });
```

and finally to get a user with his/her roles and organizations:

```js
const user = await User.findByPk(userId,
  include: [{
    model: UserOrganization,
    required : true,
    include: [
        {
            model: Role,
            required : true
        },
        {
            model: Organization,
            required : true
        },
    ],
}]);
```

This is not exactly what you wished to get because here you'll get all user's role-organization pairs. You can't get user's distinct organizations and inside each one to get distinct roles of this user because of your data structure.

Comment: Would you propose a different approach ? I though about storing the user-organization relationship on 1 table and then based on that relationship to store the multiple roles on another table `user_organization_roles` where there's a foreign key that points to the `user_organization` table to avoid having 2 foreign keys ( user + role )

Comment: That might work. I just got the above solution so that you shouldn't change a DB structure. But if you're ready to do this it's the whole different story!

Comment: Actually changed it to the above and its working. Although I had to use some `hasMany` relationships though I prefer the `belongsToMany`. But overall as a DB structure do you think it's better this way ?

Comment: Can a user be in two or more different organizations?